# fetch Problem : Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I haven't a big idea on fetching in react.I'm trying to connect my node_API running on port 8000.it all worked fine at first but not until i added a fetch for another function
this is the error
error in request.js

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';
async function httpGetPlanets() {
       7 | const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/planets`);
       8 | // Load planets and return as JSON.
    >  9 | return await response.json();
         | ^  10 | }


 13 | 
  14 | async function httpGetLaunches() {
  15 |   const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/launches`,{method:'GET'});
> 16 |   const fetchedLaunches = await response.json();
  17 |   return fetchedLaunches.sort((a, b) => {
  18 |     return a.flightNumber - b.flightNumber;
  19 |   });

error in usePlanet.js

     6 | const [planets, savePlanets] = useState([]);
       7 | 
       8 | const getPlanets = useCallback(async () => {
    >  9 |   const fetchedPlanets = await httpGetPlanets();
         | ^  10 |   savePlanets(fetchedPlanets);
      11 | }, []);
      12 |   15 | const [isPendingLaunch, setPendingLaunch] = useState(false);

  

  17 | const getLaunches = useCallback(async () => {
> 18 |   const fetchedLaunches = await httpGetLaunches();
     | ^  19 |   saveLaunches(fetchedLaunches);
  20 | }, []);
  21 |
```

this us the function that I added:

```
async function httpSubmitLaunch(launch) {
  try {
    //await the promise returned by the fetch function when we make a post request to our api_url 
     return await fetch(`${API_URL}/launches`, {
      method: "post",
      // if we pass json we have to fix one header
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(launch)
    }) 
 }
     catch (err) {
    return {
      ok: false,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with `fetch` itself, but I found that there was a problem in the connection between the model and the controller.